# How to change python version while executing in java

Tags: java, python-3.x, cmd, environment-variables, anaconda

I have two version of python installed in my system. One is **python 3.4** which is in my ***c: drive /python34***, and the other one is from ***anaconda which is python 3.5 in a diffrenet folder***. 
I had my python 3.4 set in my envirnment path and removed it from there.
Now if I use ***python --version*** command in my cmd the version it gives is 3.5 which is what I need so my programs will work fine.[image]

But if I run it through my java runtime it show it is using pyhton 3.4.
Note: I removed the python 3.4 from my enviroment path, its no more there. Still how is my java code picking the same old python.
here's my java code

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

    String[] cmd = {

            "python",
            "--version"

        };      
    execLocal(cmd, result);     
}
```

And the result I got was:
[image]

And how should I ask java to pick the different version of the python.
Feel free to point my mistakes if you found it. I am ready to learn from my mistakes, you can also come up with new ideas or changes if required.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to use the absolute path to the Anaconda Python.

I used `ProcessBuilder` and set the `ProcessBuilder` command to be `/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python` following with the Python script name and any other arguments.

HTH